# Does scp allow inline file renaming in destination?

Tags: scp

For instance, I have tried this (notice sources is remote):

```
scp root@$node:/sourcepath/sourcefile.log /destinationpath/destinationfile.log
```

The other option is to rename the file afterwards, but would be more convenient to do it on the fly while the data is downloaded via scp, therein my question. Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean? file is saved remotely with another name

Comment: What about the command that you tried didn't work? It looks fine to me, provided `$node` contains something sane, `/sourcepath/sourcefile.log` exists and is readable on whatever host `$node` resolves to, and `/destinationpath` exists and is writeable by you locally... Perhaps you need to use `${node}:` instead of `$node:`, though...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe without scp:

```
ssh yourserver "cat >tmpfile && mv tmpfile datafile" <datafile
```

This command copies the "datafile" file to a remote server under the name "tmpfile".

Only after successful copy renames the temporary file "tmpfile" to the right name "datafile" on remote host.

If copying was not successful, the remote host will be only a temporary file.

Thus, you are protected from getting no full "datafile" file.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: Well, I wrote more detail.